# How can I select the correct unicode font for python PIL draw.text?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, fonts, python-imaging-library, python-unicode

I am trying to draw unicode text with an unknown language into an image using PIL draw.text. I would like to use the google noto fonts to do this.

The problem is that no font file contains all the unicode characters so I need to select the correct font file to pass to draw.text e.g. to render Japanese I need to load the "Noto Sans CJK JP" font file but for French the "Noto Sans" font file. I understand that it isn't possible to merge all the fonts into one big file.

How can I choose the correct file for my unicode?uni

Comment: Can you clarify, are you asking how to select a font in PIL specifically? Or just generally how to pick a font that includes characters for the text you want to image?

Comment: I know how to select a font, my problem is knowing which font to select for the given unicode string.

Comment: I am using code2000.ttf at the moment but it isn't very pretty and doesn't have everything.